# Getting error There was an error parsing the query while fetching data from CE mdf database in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am developing an application in C# VS 2010.

I am using CE database to this.
My code is

```
string con = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\Acadamy.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
string cmd = "SELECT sid as 'Student No', sname as 'Student Name', contact as 'Contact No' FROM Student WHERE"
                     + " status='Active'";
var dt = new DataTable();
using (var a = new SqlCeDataAdapter())
  {
    try
     {
      a.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand();
      a.SelectCommand.Connection = new SqlCeConnection(con);
      a.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      a.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmd;
      a.Fill(dt);
      dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
  }
```

I am getting error stating that

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 17,Token in error = Student No ]

Not getting what's wrong with the code.

When I query like below it works.

```
SELECT sid, sname, contact FROM Student WHERE status = 'Active'
```

There is I think there is something else problem.

Comment: Your sql seems ok. Have you run the desired query in management studio?

Comment: Try to run the query with the aliases.

Comment: Yap, Found the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Finally what was the problem?

Comment: problem was as you told aliases. Updated code is `string cmd = "SELECT  sid AS [Student ID], sname AS [Student Name], contact AS [Contact No] FROM Student WHERE status='Active'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used query like below :

```
"SELECT sid AS [Student ID], sname AS [Student Name], contact AS [Contact No] FROM Student WHERE status='Active'";
```